# ¿Puede alguien decirme donde tengo el error?

Tags: python

```
def asignacion_paquetes(U,m,v):
    P={}
    for u in range(U+1):
        P[0,u] =0
    for i in range(1,len(m)+1):
        P[i,0]=0
        for u in range(1,U+1):
            P[i,u] = max(P[i-1, u-x]+v[i,x] for x in range(0,min(u,m[i])+1))

    return P[len(m),U]
```

Me gustaria saber donde esta el error porque me dice `IndexError: list index out of range` en la linea en la que pongo la flecha ->
Este codigo representa a un problema de optimizacion de asignacion optima de recursos resuelto por programacion dinamica U representa los recursos totales y m es una lista que representa el limite de recursos que se puede asignar a una actividad i y v es un diccionario que tiene como clave una tupla i,u que representa el beneficio de asignar un recurso u a una actividad i.
Todo esto con el objetivo de obtener el mayor beneficio.
De ahi la formula `P[i,u]= max(P[i-1,u-x] + v[i,x]`.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
U = 12

m = [2,4,2,4,2]

v=dict(((i,u),randrange(100)) for i in range(1,len(m)+1) for u in range(0, U+1))
```

Esos son los valores de los parámetros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema con él uso de `range()`, no sé si tienes claro que en Python los índices de cualquier colección de datos comienzan en `0` y el límite superior de `range()` no es inclusivo. Puntualmente el error lo tienes en el `for` más profundo:

```
for i in range(1,len(m)+1):
    P[i,0]=0
    for u in range(1,U+1):
        P[i,u] = max(P[i-1, u-x]+v[i,x] for x in range(0,min(u,m[i])+1))
```

El primer `for` iterará desde `i=1` hasta la longitud de `m`, con los diccionarios no tienes problema, el problema lo tienes cuando haces `m[i]`, como `m` es una lista cuyos índices comienzan en `0`, y tu desplazas el mismo 1 valor más el último índice de la iteración no existe de ahí el error. Debieras en todo caso hacer `m[i-1]`.

Algunos comentarios extra:

- Yo manejaría las claves de los diccionarios con el mismo esquema de los índices de las listas dónde `0` es el primer elemento, esto haría más consistente el código
- También para que sea más claro, al definir las claves de los diccionarios usaría los parentesis para cerrar las tuplas, por ejemplo: `P[(i,0)]=0` para no confundir a nadie con algún manejo especial de índices.

Comment: Pues muchas gracias por toda la explicacion la verdad, si lo de los indices lo tengo claro, este codigo es de los apuntes del profesor cosa que supuestamente a el si le funciona y a mi pues me salta ese error en muchos de sus codigos. Muchas gracias de verdad me estaba dando muchos dolores de cabeza